# N-bit number $m'$ , such that $m' = m \mod 2$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I was reading a paper about fully homomorphic encryption and I stumbled upon the following text:

> if To encrypt a bit $m ∈ \{0,1\}$, set $m′$ to be a random *N-bit* number such that
>   $ m′ = m \mod 2$.

I don't understand this. From what I understand the only two possible values of `m mod 2` are `0` and `1` ? Then how can `m'` be generalized to a `N-bit number` ?

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand the notion

$$m'=m\text{ mod } 2$$

It doesn't mean that $m'$ is equal to $m\text{ mod } 2$. The "$
\text{mod}$" part applies to "$=$", not to "$m$". What it means is simply that $m'-m$ is divisble by $2$ (or in other words that $m'$ and $m$ give the same remainder when divided by $2$) . The author probably should've used

$$m'\equiv m\text{ mod } 2$$

but $=$ is generally acceptable as well.

Comment: Thanks, this made it clear!

Answer (score 1):

$m'$ is a random $N$ bit number with a certain final bit. All the other $N-1$ bits you are free to choose (perhaps randomly, perhaps $N$-bit means specifically that it must be between $2^{N-1}$ and $2^N$). That's all it means.

mod is not an operation. It is not the same as `%` in many programming languages. It's a specification of what the relation $=$ (or more correctly $\equiv$) means (i.e. if you use `%` on *both sides*, you get the same answer). It might be more intuitive to write something like $m' \equiv_2 m$, if that helps. It's not a standard notation, but it is loads better than the standard mod notation in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks. It does help! I like your first paragraph! :)

Comment: this is hard, two equally acceptable answers at almost equal times.

Comment: Don't think too much about it. I'm not here to get check marks. I'm here to help people and answer interesting problems.